# exe.config not updating properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging

I'm having issues with my settings file when I debug my code in VS. I have added a double and changed two values (bool and int) in my Settings.settings. The change is reflected in Settings.Designer and also in app.Config. When I run my code, the added double functions properly but the boolean and the int are the old values. When I go into my bin/debug to look at exe.config, it reflects the old settings file where the old values are unchanged and there is no added double value. I tried setting Copy Always to true for Settings but all that did was create a Properties folder in bin/debug with a settings and settings.designer file that matches what I want the exe.config to look like but the exe.config file is still the old one.

If it's using that exe.config file it would explain why the old values are unchanged but then why can it see the added double? If it's using the correct Settings file as reflected in VS Settings, Designer and app.config then it should be using the updated values for the existing values. If I drop a correct exe.config file into the bin/debug folder, then it sees the new values so the issue seems to be with the initial generation of the file but as far as I can tell the Settings and Settings.Designer files reflect what I want so I'm not sure what else to check. I've tried deleting everything in the bin/debug folder both manually and by using clean and in both cases, it regenerates the exe.config without the new value and with the old existing values. When I install the project using Visual Studios setup project, the installed version has a correctly generated exe.config file so it seems to only happen while debugging, but I need these values changed when I debug. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to show us some facts to get the question out of its current "it doesn't work" state.  Google "visual studio increase build verbosity".  You don't have to post everything you see, just the part where it starts noodling about app.config

Comment: The issue resolved when I updated my VS version to 15.9.2. Thanks for suggesting the build verbosity though, I think that will be a useful resource in the future.